# how to bind multi-word headers to it's values from csv as a dictionery

Tags: python-3.x, csv, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm scraping data from an HTML table and want to bind multi-word headers together as a dictionary keys for the correct values.
How should I bind the correct headers?
How should I remove unwanted headers at the end?

```py
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for span in all_spans:
        num_page_items = len(all_spans)
        f.write(span.text)
driver.close()


with open(filename) as csvfile:  # Reading csv file 
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    mydict = {}
    for col in csvreader:
        print(col)
```

I expect the output to look something like -

> > > Symbol{'AIZ', ('Shares': 1520), ('Purchase Price': 106.31), ('Market Price': 111.59), ('Total Value': 169,616.80), ('Gain/Loss': 8,025.60), ('Gain/Loss %': 0.050%)}

If i use csv.DictReader I'm getting -

> > > OrderedDict([('Symbol', 'AIZ'), ('Shares', '1520'), ('Purchase', '$106.31'), ('Price', '$8,025.60'), ('Market', '$169,616.80'), ('Total', '0.050%'), ('Value', 'Buy'), ('Gain/Loss', 'Sell'), ('%', None), ('Actions', None)])

And if I`ll use csv.reader I'm getting -

> > > ['AIZ', '1520', '$106.31', '$111.59', '$169,616.80', '$8,025.60', '0.050%', 'Buy', '|', 'Sell']

[Output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in2IV.png)

Comment: The ordered dict doesn't seem to be recognizing the header line, can you show the CSV file content (at least for the data you have posted)?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/in2IV.png